# Google Python Style Guide & relative imports

Tags: python, import, relative-import, google-style-guide

Google Python Style Guide [says](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#224-decision):

> Do not use relative names in imports. Even if the module is in the same package, use the full package name. This helps prevent unintentionally importing a package twice.

What would be a sample setup that incurs importing a package twice?

Comment: Maybe it’s a vague reference to the issues with `__main__`?

Comment: @DavisHerring What issues are you referring to?

Comment: `python -m` is very broken in that, to support the silly `__name__` check used to cram an entry point into a module, it runs a **copy** of the module that can end up importing the original.  (Using `python -m` to run a *package* mostly avoids these issues.)  That doesn’t sound quite the same as what Google is saying here (which is why this isn’t an answer), but it’s the closest match I know.

Comment: That does sound like a kind of thing this could be about. Could you point me to where this is documented though? I was able to reproduce contents of a module seemingly executing twice, but there appears to be no difference in the behavior of absolute vs. relative imports. For example, `print('A', __name__); import b` in `a.py` and `print('B'); import a` in `b.py`, then `python a.py` results in `A __main__`, `B`, `A a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reference to the Python 2 behavior ([deprecated since 2.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)) of **implicit relative imports**: allowing `import bar` in a module in a package `foo` to refer to the module `foo.bar`.  Consider a directory on `sys.path` that looks like

```
…
|-- client.py
`-- pkg
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- mod.py
    `-- script.py
```

with files having the following contents:

### `client.py`

```
print "client..."
from pkg import mod,script
print "client!"
```

### `pkg/__init__.py`

```
print "pkg"
```

### `pkg/mod.py`

```
print "mod: %r"%__name__
```

### `pkg/script.py`

```
print "script:",__name__,__package__

if __name__=='__main__':
  import mod,client
  print "script!"
```

In this setup `mod` can easily be imported twice:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=… python …/pkg/script.py
script: __main__ None
mod: 'mod'
client...
pkg
mod: 'pkg.mod'
script: pkg.script None
client!
script!
```

In an attempt to reduce configuration overhead, Python adds the directory `pkg` to `sys.path`, effectively presuming that `script.py` is a top-level module `script`.  Unfortunately, that means that `import mod` creates a **top-level** module named `mod`, and the explicit import of `pkg.mod` later causes another copy of it to exist with its full name (just after importing `pkg` itself).

It was [recognized](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#id17) that this poses a problem, and later `-m` [was adjusted](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) to tell the module being executed about the package in which it was found so that relative imports (implicit or explicit) work properly:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=… python -m pkg.script
pkg
script: __main__ pkg
mod: 'pkg.mod'
client...
script: pkg.script None
client!
script!
```

Note that `pkg` is now imported first (by `-m` itself!), that `script` now has a `__package__` attribute immediately afterwards, and that `mod` is imported just once.  Of course, `script` *itself* is (still) loaded twice, since its name gets replaced with `__main__` the first time so that `from pkg import script` finds it under a different name.

The **moral** is that implementing "a module can also be a script" in terms of `__name__=='__main__'` is fundamentally broken (and replacements [have been rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0299/)): a module already *has* a `__name__`, and creating a separate module object to be the entry point so that its `__name__` can differ is as absurd as copying the Java class (and all its static data) that provides `main`.  Making a module that no one ever imports works, but is oxymoronic (and breaks code inspection that imports all members of a package).